# Seasonal adjustment question, why do days matter?

Tags: regression, time-series, seasonality

I have a simple ols equation where the independent variable is total production in a month. I seasonally adjust the data with an x12 and run the ols and get my estimates. The strange thing is, if I change the independent variable to average production per day by dividing by the number of days in the month, and then seasonally adjusting the series my R-squared goes up by almost 0.1. Does anyone have any idea why that might be?

Comment: If production depends on the amount of time invested in it (which is a reasonable assumption), then the result is as expected. You are reflecting a relevant feature in the second model, but you are not reflecting it in the first one; hence, no wonder that the second model has a higher $R^2$. That should happen regardless of seasonality. However, seasonality may mess things up.

Comment: I don't follow you. The same information is in both series just presented a difference way.

Comment: Well, one of us is too quick: either I did not quite get the setting right, or you did not quite get the idea behind my argument. Some more time spent reflecting should help :)

Comment: Why do you say the first one doesn't reflect time invested? Shouldnt the seasonal adjustment correct for the number of days in the month?

Comment: If it does, then my comment is irrelevant. I do not know exactly what x12 does.

Comment: Oh, well it's supposed to seasonally adjust data and one of the things it factors in is the number of days in the month. But my question implies it doesn't fully account for that.